ATTRIBUTEERROR: module 'mysqldb.constants.er' has no attribute 'constraint_failed'
im trying to connect Mysql database with my django project. i get this after running my project:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\python\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 126, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 40, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 143, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 371, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 231, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 193, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)
  File "C:\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 23, in <module>
    from MySQLdb.converters import conversions
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .err import ProgrammingError
  File "C:\Users\shara\source\repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\pymysql\err.py", line 129, in <module>
    ER.CONSTRAINT_FAILED,
AttributeError: module 'MySQLdb.constants.ER' has no attribute 'CONSTRAINT_FAILED'

i have python 3.10, imported pymysql and MySQLdb in settings. already changed DATABASES section in settings.I do not know in what way solve this error. What should i do? and what is the attribute 'CONSTRAINT_FAILD'?
